# Install JMSSerializerBundle

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, symfony-2.0

I installed `FOSRestBundle` but it needs `JMSSerializerBundle`.

I added in my deps the next lines:

```
[JMSSerializerBundle]
    git=git://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle.git
    target=bundles/JMS/SerializerBundle
```

Here it explains how to do it: http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle/master/installation

but when I try `$php bin/vendors install` it shows me an error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                          
  The service definition "jms_serializer.serializer" does not exist.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The manual says it to register the bundle with the kernel:

```
new JMS\Serializer\JMSSerializerBundle($this),
```

but the installer create the folder: `vendor/bundles/JMS/SerializerBundle`

so, it must be added the next line to the AppKernel.php instead of the other:

```
new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle($this),
```

Answer (score 4):

You should comment the `new FOS\RestBundle\FOSRestBundle(),` line in `AppKernel.php` in the `registerBundles()` method. Then install the `JmsSerializerBundle` and after that you should decommend that line and register the `JsmSerializerBundle`.

Comment: I did that at the beginning but it doesn't work, it shows that error

Answer (score 2):

Did you also do the following steps from the manual? Sounds to me like you didn't add the line

```
new JMS\Serializer\JMSSerializerBundle($this)
```

to AppKernel.php

Comment: if I do that it shows this error: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'JMS\Serializer\JMSSerializerBundle' not found in ../app/AppKernel.php on line 21

Comment: That's probably because you didn't register the namespaces with the autoloader. Like it says in the installation instructions.

Comment: I think mattsches is right and you didnt follow all steps in the manual.

Comment: I have `'JMS' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',` in the `app/AppKernel.php` file, because I installed `JMSSecurityExtraBundle`